# TV program like DSCaler?

Tags: software-recommendation, tv-tuner

I have a wii console plugged to a TV card on my PC, and connected to a monitor, I would like to have that computer with a small operating system (maybe ubuntu-server with the minimum available GUI, and with access to the TV card).

The only problem is that, for the moment, the solution that I have found makes me use a Windows XP with DScaler, and I wanted something lighter, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to previous questions related to TV Tuners, may be also helpful for you:

[How to scan for analog cable channels on a DVB-T USB tuner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45357/how-to-scan-for-analog-cable-channels-on-a-dvb-t-usb-tuner/45391#45391)

[Can anybody help me to make Kworld UB445-Q TV tuner work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58547/can-anybody-help-me-to-make-kworld-ub445-q-tv-tuner-work/58636#58636)

Take a look at these, TvTime and MeTV are working pretty fine in the majority of the distros, even the lightweight.

TV Time is my favorite, and I am currently using it, which features smart image resizing, full screen in several formats (PAL, NTSC, Widescreen, 4:3, etc.). I can't say for MeTV but I am sure it has its own features.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

## [Me TV](https://launchpad.net/me-tv) (available in software center)

> Me TV is a digital television viewer for GNOME.
>
> Me TV was developed for the modern digital lounge room with a PC for a media centre that is capable of normal PC tasks (web surfing, word processing and watching TV).

Comment: I don't know much about Me TV or the Wii, but does Me TV work for analog TV? Or does the Wii have a digital output (DVB or ATSC)?